# How to get the authenticated users in a heroku dyno?

Tags: heroku-cli, dyno

Does anyone know how I can get the credentials of the logged user in a heroku dyno?

Context: We are trying to log access to Heroku production `rails console`. People access it via `heroku run` or `heroku exec`. Heroku does authenticate the users executed the command, however, I'm unable to retrieve this information once the rails console is started.

It looks like `heroku` cli is not available in the dyno, and `whoami` returns `dyno`.

Eg:

```
$ heroku run rails c -a opt-prod

<in rails console> 

irb(main):001:0> ENV
irb(main):001:0> `whoami`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We contacted Heroku and there is no option to do this. Instead,

> A running dyno doesn't contain
>   information on the user that started the process, so there's no way to
>   get the "current user" from inside a dyno on Heroku.
>
> However, one idea for a workaround is to grab the current Heroku CLI
>   user and sends it along with the console command when starting.
>   Something like this will work:
>
> ```
> CURRENT_HEROKU_USER="$CURRENT_HEROKU_USER" rails c --app my-app-name
>
> > Running CURRENT_HEROKU_USER=chap@heroku.com rails c...
>
> ENV['CURRENT_HEROKU_USER']
>
> > "chap@heroku.com"
> ```
>
> The downside of this approach is there's no way to validate that value from inside the dyno. However you could use
>   your application logs to retroactively verify the info. The API will
>   log the user who started the console process in your application logs:
>
> ```
> CURRENT_HEROKU_USER=chap@heroku.com rails c by user chap@heroku.com
> ```
>
> I'm sorry we don't have a better answer for you here.
>
> Please let me know if I can be of more help.